# Logo component - In design mode unable to see the edit toolbar for this component

Tags: aem

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"
%> 

<div class="container_16">
<div class="grid_8">
<cq:include path="logo" resourceType="/apps/traningCQ5/components/logo" />
    </div>
<div class="grid_8">
<div class="search_area">
<div> userinfo </div>
<div> toptoolbar </div>
<div> search </div>
<div
class="clear"></div> </div>
</div>

</div>
```

The above code includes logo component. This is added in header.jsp however, if I add this component anywhere else it works but not in header.

Could any please help me in this ?

Comment: Can you check if there is any JS errors that are shown in the console? Does your logo component component contain all the configurations similar to the one present in the foundation/components/logo?

Comment: try doing your include as a script file instead.

    <cq:include script="/apps/trainingCQ5/components/logo.jsp"/>

Comment: on console i get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: CQ is not defined" . And all the configuration is similar to foundation/components/logo.

@Alisneaky -- we cannot include jsp directly in this manner. If we do that our content inside jsp wont even get displayed.